# why Does "navigator.userAgent" in javaScript returns the String "Mozilla" when tried in a google chrome borwser?

Tags: javascript, navigator, browserid

Im developing a javaScript code and I want to determine the version and brand of the client's browser,  here's the piece of code I'm using to do so :

```
var browserName ; 
function BrowserCheckin () 
{

    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mozilla") > 0 )
        browserName = "Mozilla" ;
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > 0 )
        browserName = "InternetExplorer";
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") > 0)
        browserName= "Google Chrome" ; 
    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") > 0 ) 
        browserName = "Opera" ; 
    document.write("<h1>"  + browserName + "</h1>") ;
}
```

but when i run my code using "Google Chrome" , the useAgent property returns a string containting :

> "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30 "

But I don't get what that "Mozilla/5.0" is doing there , anyone has any Idea ?
(and one more thing , I use Linux as my Operating System)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You ought to look into feature detection, rather than browser detection, if you're wanting to enable/disable functionality.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I'll look into that ,You're right :) if it was an answer i would have chosen it as the best answer :) thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For [historical reasons](http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/), nearly all browsers (except Opera) prepend `Mozilla/` to their user agent.

For example, here are some common user agents:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko)
            Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30                    # Chrome 12
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) Gecko Firefox/5.0                # FF 5
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 9.0; en-US)        # IE 9
Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.8.119 Version/11.10  # Opera 11.10
```

For a detailed list, refer to [online](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) [databases](http://www.user-agents.org/).

Comment: thanks , so quick , but it's not the case for Opera and IE. they don't have the 'Mozilla/' in their userAgent .

Comment: @Delan Azabani : It's what Opera gives : Opera/9.80(X11;Linux x86_64; U;en)Presto/2.9.168 Version/11.50

Comment: @SpiXel Added some examples to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

That *is* the user agent string for Chrome. It has Mozilla in the name for historical reasons. Even funnier is when you see Mozilla in the user agent string for Internet Explorer :)

This link has UA strings for Chrome, you might find it useful: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/.