# Workaround for file input label click (Firefox) - jQuery 1.9

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, input, label

First of all this is very similiar to:
[Workaround for file input label click (Firefox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742278/workaround-for-file-input-label-click-firefox)

but the provided solution is not working in jQuery 1.9+

The $.browser variable dosn't exist anymore because now we have to do [feature detection](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/).

I would very much like to detect the feature that I need but there seems to be no such support in jQuery.
Browser detection is gone, feature detection seems not able to detect what I need, is there a good solution out there?
A Modernizr solution would be appreciated aswell and also plain-vanilla-js solution  is accepted

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you mean reversing the order, that is not a solution.

Comment: I meant using the label click -> input click trigger solution, but that would result in double file dialogs in other browsers. I can't think of a way to detect support for this, so i'd suggest just looking at the useragent and detecting the specific browser and version(s) that is having this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ( window.mozIndexedDB !== undefined ) {
   //do firefox things
}
```

This will only return true in Firefox, afaik.

Example test:

```
if ( window.mozIndexedDB !== undefined ) {
   alert('You are using Firefox');
}
```

You can try looking at window.navigator.userAgent but I don't recommend it, a bunch of other browsers identify as Mozilla, see this question for some examples: [Why Does “navigator.userAgent” in javaScript returns the String “Mozilla” when tried in a google chrome borwser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050521/why-does-navigator-useragent-in-javascript-returns-the-string-mozilla-when-t)

Comment: My Firefox returns undefined when accessing window.Mozilla

Comment: is this any better then `navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox')!==-1`  ?

Comment: If they're both in place and correct, no practical difference, but some devices send weird user agent info.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best practice, but why don't you try the [jQuery Migrate plugin](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js)? It brings back $.browser, aswell some other removed features.

Comment: Because that's another 16.7kb just to check wether this is a firefox browser.